# Importer for Greenbutton data, an initiative by US gov

Tags: python, utc

Here are the details of it,
[Greebutton](http://www.greenbuttondata.org/)

I want to import this data provided by green_button.
You can find the sample data files [here](http://pge.com/greenbutton/)

It gives out data in two formats, viz. CSV and XML.
So, my question is the data provided are in which timezone? Are the data in UTC timezone ?..then i do not need any sort of conversion. But, if it is in local timezone then i need to convert it to UTC. Because, my importer only accepts UTC timezone's data.

If anyone know any sort of details about this Green button initiative then please revert back.

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Thanks & regards,
Aashish P.

Comment: Utility metering data is usually reported in Local Standard Time (so daylight savings, if appropriate, is not applied). The hour reporting might seem a little odd to programmers: metering is reported at the end of hours 1-24 for a given day. Some utilities will report this last meter interval at 23:59:59 by convention. It's done this way to keep the final hour of the day billed with that day/month rather than the next. ISO 8601 allows this, though most computer implementations will only write times 00:00:00-23:59:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [XMI](http://collaborate.nist.gov/twiki-sggrid/pub/SmartGrid/PAP10Objective3/naesb_eui.xsd) the XML time data is in [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - in the sample XML it seems to be UTC.

Comment: Yes. You are right. In XML it seems to be in UTC. But what about CSV data? Any comments on that ?

Answer (score 0):

If the csv time data is different than the xml time data, then I would guess that it is the local time for "OAKLAND, CA 94611," the location listed in the csv file. In that case it would be UTC-8, or UTC-7 during daylight savings time (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone).